# Is there any way to run ELinks with python-script like FireFox with Selenium webdriver with python

Tags: python, linux, selenium, browser

I just start exploring selenium, and it's great however, I would like to write a script that will use ELinks to browse webpages.

With Se webdriver I can do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Open firefox
br=webdriver.Firefox()
#open website
br.get('http://python.org')
#check if website title contains word
assert 'Python' in br.title
elem=br.find_element_by_name('q')
elem.send_keys('selenium')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert 'Google' in br.title
br.close()
```

But how to do similar task in python with Elinks? (or is it possible at all?)

Comment: whats the motivation for this? just trying to understand the need more to better answer the question

Comment: From my point of view, ELinks is faster than any GUI browsers, and I just want to get some iformation from web page, I can't use urllib2 or some libraries like mechanize for that, because web site has a very strong anti bot protection, so one way I think will work is to make Elinks go the page and then somehow get the data out of there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

elinks is really fast. You can [automate elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/html/manual.html-chunked/ch14.html) with the Lua scripting language. There are [example scripts](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/html/manual.html-chunked/ch14s04.html) in their docs. You can also try [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) which is a really great way to automate terminal applications in python. The below script uses pexpect to do the same task as the example in the question. It will visit python.org, search for selenium, save the search results to a file, and then exit elinks.

```
from pexpect import spawn
import time
import datetime

KEY_UP = '\x1b[A'
KEY_DOWN = '\x1b[B'
KEY_RIGHT = '\x1b[C'
KEY_LEFT = '\x1b[D'
KEY_ESCAPE = '\x1b'
KEY_BACKSPACE = '\x7f'

child = spawn('elinks http://python.org')
print 'waiting for python.org to load'
child.expect('Python')
time.sleep(0.1)
print 'doing selenium search'
child.sendline('/advanced search')
child.sendline(KEY_UP * 2)
child.sendline('selenium')
child.sendline('')
print 'waiting for search results'
child.expect('Google Search')
time.sleep(0.1)
print 'saving html'
child.send(KEY_ESCAPE)  # bring up menu
child.send(KEY_DOWN + 's')  # select save as in menu
child.send(KEY_BACKSPACE * 100) # remove any file name already in input box
file = './saved_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S') + '.html'
child.sendline(file)
#child.interact() #uncomment to interact with elinks, good for debugging
print 'quiting'
child.sendline('q')
child.wait()
```

Comment: I updated the answer with a pexpect script that automates elinks

Comment: Perfect. To download a file and interact with dialogues:  os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = "genproxy:8080" child = spawn('elinks -auto-submit http://somesite.com/somefile.zip') print 'waiting for site to load' time.sleep(3) child.sendline('v') child.sendline('') child.sendline('') time.sleep(300)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has a headless browser option, [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).  htmlunit still doesn't have a full javascript implementation, but it has a lot of it-- you can use it until it breaks.

Alternatively, Chrome is very quick, regardless.  I use chrome for my webdriver automation, and Chrome is fast enough that I end up experiencing port exhaustion if I don't code timing properly.